# output cat results to cursor linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is there a way to load cat results into cursor? For example if I did `cat test.txt` and I want to paste the results in the next shell, I would like the results to be in the cursor rather than copying it again. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Looks like you're looking for a [pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix))

Comment: What do you mean by "results to be in the cursor" ? what "cursor" ?

Comment: Maybe OP means that the results should be in the clipboard?

Comment: OP could you give an example of what you want to achieve? 'Cursor' is not a term generally used in relation to shells

Comment: And in any case, this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "results to be in the cursor" you mean you want to put them on the clipboard, you can do following :

```
cat test.txt | xclip -selection c
```

this is similar to what happens when you press `ctrl + c`

and to paste it somewhere you can do :

```
xclip -selection clipboard -o
```

this is similar to what happens when you press `ctrl + v`

You can further add these lines to your `~/.bashrc`

```
alias termCopy='xclip -selection c'
alias termPaste='xclip -selection clipboard -o'
```

This will allow you to use aliases instead of the original commands.